# Alert not showing when presented to view controller that is having webview

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I am trying to show alert box in my view controller that is having a webview using WKWebView.I have a sidemenu which i created in another class inheriting UIView and that sidemenu is having an option of logout.So I want that as soon as I click on logout option the side menu should remove from superview and an alert comes.

I have created sidemenu and removed the view when option is clicked.Now I just want to show the alert.But that is not happening.

```
     func logout(){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Do you want to logout from the application", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    let vc = WebViewController()
    vc.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

     }
```

Alert should come up as soon as logout option is clicked.

Comment: how can you display WKWebview in view? present it?or push?

Comment: I am displaying wkwebview in view controller but my fuction is in another class which is inheriting the UIView and want to show the alert into Viewcontroller after the logout click is happend in UIView

Answer (score 0):

Your VC (i.e WebViewController) is not presented yet.

Use `self.present(...)` method on current ViewController like:

```
 func logout(){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Do you want to logout from the application", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

     }
```

Comment: I am using this function in another class thats why i am creating an object of that class and then presenting

Answer (score 0):

problem is here when you write

```
let vc = WebViewController()
```

create new  object of WebViewController() so that alert is present in that new object that you create not in previous one or call function logout() from other view

so you need to pass object of UIViewController where you need to present alert

```
 func logout(vc: UIViewController){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Do you want to logout from the application", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    vc.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

     }
```

how to call

```
logout(vc: self)
```

Comment: After implementing your code this error is coming:   Cannot convert value of type 'WebViewController.Type' to expected argument type 'WebViewController'

Comment: WebViewController is UIViewController and SideBar is UIVIEW

Comment: @SmartCoder you just need to pass UIViewController object where you need to present alert

Comment: please help with example